Pipenv packages install using requirements.txt
I'm working on a large Python framework built from about fifty packages; these packages and all their dependencies (400 more packages!) are referenced in several requirements.txt files for all supported Python versions, which are versioned with Git and stored in a remote repository.
When I'm deploying an application using this framework, and depending on the application context, I may have to install only a subset of my framework packages, not all of them.
So my question is: I know I can install all packages defined in a requirements file; but when installing only one or more packages, how can I be sure that all installed packages versions (including dependencies!) are those which are defined in my requirements file?

If you are using pipenv, then the requirements file should be used only as a way to construct the necessary Pipfile, not as an ongoing resource used by pipenv.
